# android:Is it possible to encrypt the folder

Tags: android, file, encryption, aes, android-gallery

Sorry for asking this question but i am not getting clear idea of encrypting and decrypting a folder, I am trying to encrypt a bunch of selected images as mentioned in this post          [encrypt/decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782187/how-to-encrypt-file-from-sd-card-using-aes-in-android) but it is taking lot of time to encrypt bunch of selected images,so i tried to encrypt a folder  containing selected images but it is giving me filenotfoundexception:open failed(is a directory)  I have updated encrypt function as shown below

```
static void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
// Here you read the cleartext.
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.myapp/.private");
// This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.myapp/.encyrpted");

// Length is 16 byte
SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
// Create cipher
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
// Wrap the output stream
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
// Write bytes
int b;
byte[] d = new byte[8];
while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
    cos.write(d, 0, b);
}
// Flush and close streams.
cos.flush();
cos.close();
fis.close();}
```

so how do i encrypt folder sdcard/.myapp/.private so that i can reduce time in encrypting whole bunch of images??

Comment: see this may be its helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266076/can-we-encrypt-a-folder-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to encrypt folder as well as sub contain data.

See this may be its helpful to you.

[Can we Encrypt a folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266076/can-we-encrypt-a-folder-in-android)

Comment: sorry i am new to android,i saw that post before posting my question,. but i dint get any idea on how to encrypt a particular folder,<a href="http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesFile.html">link</a> was vague for me to understand

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787328/rsa-encrypt-and-decrypt-strings-on-android i am not sure it will works for folder

Comment: i think you should encrypt and decrepit zip folder try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222284/encrypting-and-decrypting-a-zip-file-in-android

Comment: Thanks for your response but i just want to hide or encrypt a folder so that other person must not be able to see my hidden pictures,i was able to hide the images using the link i mentioned but it is taking lot of time so i thought i will hide/encrypt folder so that person exploring my sdcard wont be able to see images inside hidden folder